# Add better debug statement to overlay in VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, prototype

I use the library `bignumber.js`, which does the job of handling big/small numbers very nicely. However, debugging with VS Code is a pain, as i get the following output upon inspection:

[image: VS Code inspect of bignumber]

Is there a way for me to edit this? I've looked into prototype editing but I could not get this to work.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26234